# 503 Service Unavailable after several reloads

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat, jdbc

I have a java web application that is running on Ubuntu 14.04.
I am using apache tomcat 7.0.54, database is mysql, mysql connector version is 5.1.9.

Everytime after I restart tomcat and hit f5 several times the application won't respond anymore (keeps on loading and the main page won't open).

The web application main page calls many web services which returns json requests (restful using spring mvc and maven), all these requests will return **503 (Service Unavailable)** after a while.

I am checking the logs for any errors, catalina.out will show no errors at all (actually it will stop showing any new info)

catalina.2015-12-03.log is showing the below lines when tomcat starts (not when the error occurs):

```
- SEVERE: The web application [/xyz] created a ThreadLocal with key of
   type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Request
   attributes]) and a value of type
   [org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes] $
   Dec 03, 2015 1:01:57 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
 - SEVERE: The web application [/xyz] created a ThreadLocal with key of
   type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Locale
   context]) and a value of type
   [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet$1] (value
   [org.sprin$ Dec 03, 2015 1:01:57 PM
   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
 - SEVERE: The web application [/xyz] created a ThreadLocal with key of
   type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@52fbd8a8])
   and a value of type
   [org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl]
   (value [org$ Dec 03, 2015 1:01:57 PM
   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
 - SEVERE: The web application [/xyz] created a ThreadLocal with key of
   type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Request
   attributes]) and a value of type
   [org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes] $
   Dec 03, 2015 1:01:57 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
 - SEVERE: The web application [/xyz] created a ThreadLocal with key of
   type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Request
   attributes]) and a value of type
   [org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes] $
   Dec 03, 2015 1:01:57 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
 - SEVERE: The web application [/xyz] created a ThreadLocal with key of
   type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Locale
   context]) and a value of type
   [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet$1] (value
   [org.sprin$ Dec 03, 2015 1:01:57 PM
   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
 - SEVERE: The web application [/xyz] created a ThreadLocal with key of
   type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@52fbd8a8])
   and a value of type
   [org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl]
   (value [org$ Dec 03, 2015 1:01:57 PM
   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
 - SEVERE: The web application [/xyz] created a ThreadLocal with key of
   type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Locale
   context]) and a value of type
   [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet$1] (value
   [org.sprin$ Dec 03, 2015 1:01:57 PM
   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
 - SEVERE: The web application [/xyz] created a ThreadLocal with key of
   type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@52fbd8a8])
   and a value of type
   [org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl]
   (value [org$ Dec 03, 2015 1:01:57 PM
   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
 - SEVERE: The web application [/xyz] created a ThreadLocal with key of
   type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Request
   attributes]) and a value of type
   [org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes] $
   Dec 03, 2015 1:01:57 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
 - SEVERE: The web application [/xyz] created a ThreadLocal with key of
   type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Locale
   context]) and a value of type
   [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet$1] (value
   [org.sprin$ Dec 03, 2015 1:01:57 PM
   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks $e
   [org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@d6258b44:
   Authentication:
   org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d6258b44:
   Principal: com.dev.tima.bo.security.UserBO@6dc59dfe;$ Dec 03, 2015
   1:01:57 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
 - SEVERE: The web application [/xyz] created a ThreadLocal with key of
   type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Request
   attributes]) and a value of type
   [org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes] $
   Dec 03, 2015 1:01:57 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
 - SEVERE: The web application [/xyz] created a ThreadLocal with key of
   type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Locale
   context]) and a value of type
   [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet$1] (value
   [org.sprin$ Dec 03, 2015 1:01:57 PM
   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
 - SEVERE: The web application [/xyz] created a ThreadLocal with key of
   type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@52fbd8a8])
   and a value of type
   [org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl]
   (value [org$ Dec 03, 2015 1:01:57 PM
   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
 - SEVERE: The web application [/xyz] created a ThreadLocal with key of
   type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Request
   attributes]) and a value of type
   [org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes] $
   Dec 03, 2015 1:01:57 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
 - SEVERE: The web application [/xyz] created a ThreadLocal with key of
   type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Locale
   context]) and a value of type
   [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet$1] (value
   [org.sprin$ Dec 03, 2015 1:01:57 PM
   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
 - SEVERE: The web application [/xyz] created a ThreadLocal with key of
   type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@52fbd8a8])
   and a value of type
   [org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl]
   (value [org$ Dec 03, 2015 1:01:57 PM
   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
 - SEVERE: The web application [/xyz] created a ThreadLocal with key of
   type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Request
   attributes]) and a value of type
   [org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes] $
   Dec 03, 2015 1:01:57 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
   clearReferencesJdbc
```

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: In general this is due to wrong or absent jdbc connection management or wrongly configured transactions. Currently there is too little information.

Comment: @M.Deinum you mean too little information I provided or this error has little info?

Comment: Are you able to enhance the logging? Perhaps put log statements before and after each of the web service calls from your main page? That way you could tell if your code gets hit at all, and, if so, where it fails. Also, you say "Everytime after I restart tomcat...", does that mean you see it working eventually, and it only fails immediately after the restart, or does the application never work correctly?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave after I restart tomcat it works fine for like 10-15 minutes then it crashes, I am logging the errors for some services which are displaying service unavailable

Comment: You only added unrelated log entries. You show no configuration (show your spring config) and your entry points...

Comment: @M.Deinum what files you need to see in order to further help, the pom.xml or the root-context.xml?

Comment: the config, your class that is hit the first and some services. As stated generally this is due to wrong or absent transaction management (or even worse reloading contexts over and over).